How can I make datetime objects for the year 10,000 and beyond?
In Python 3.10.12 (or 3.x), how do I make datetime objects for dates in the year 10,000 and beyond? I get a ValueError when I try:
ValueError: year 10000 is out of range

Is there some reason this error exists? I mean, does our actual calendar not support the year 10,000, or something?

I guess they had to choose some value for the maximum year, perhaps for implementation details, and found it unlikely for anyone to need a date beyond the year 9999. There really aren’t many applications for needing precise date math beyond the next couple hundred years. Practically speaking, the Gregorian calendar might not be around by then, and at least timezone regulations will have changed enough to make the precision offered by datetime unpredictable.

I want it for making programs to assist with such as writing fiction; also, for hypothetical situations, or discussion of the future (not the present day, per se).

Can’t you just use an int for the year number then? You need second precision for hypothetical discussions?

I need it to accurately represent the full date for that year (not just the year). Seconds and minutes aren't as important as factoring in leap years, days of the week, and such, but they're still desired. I need to make conversions between different date formats, and such.

For instance, if you made a multiplayer online video game that began in the year 156,000, you might want it to represent dates accurately, right down to the second, to record when which characters did what.

But, I'm not doing that. I'm just making conversion tools and don't want them to complain at me if I try to convert dates with large years.

According to the docs and docs only 4-digits year is supported in Python. That's organic problem of old standards.
